# Getting a false value of integer from view in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an error in my asp.net mvc application. i have this view :

```
@if (Model == null || Model[1] == null || Model[1].Count == 0) 
{
    <label>Pas de demande</label>
                         }
else{
    int i = 1;
    string s = "";
    <form action="\Travail\Validation_Reservation" method="post">
@foreach( Planning.Models.Affectation v in Model[1]){
    if (v.Periode == 1) { s = "matinale"; }
    else { s = " Après midi"; }
    int a = v.Id_affectation; 
     <div><h5 style="color:blue">@i / Demande de reservation de vehicule @veh.Matricule : le @v.Date_affectation , la periode @s</h5>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@a" />
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="valider" />
   <input type="submit" name="btn" value="refuser" /></div>
    <br />
    i++;
     }
        </form>
```

and this action:

```
public ActionResult Validation_Reservation() {
            string btn = Request.Params["btn"];
            string id_string = Request.Params["id"];
            int id_affectation = int.Parse(id_string);
            Owner resp = new Owner();
            if (btn == "valider") {
                resp.Accepter_Reservation(id_affectation);
                return RedirectToAction("Notification");
                  }
            resp.Refuser_Reservation(id_affectation);
            return RedirectToAction("Notification");
         }
```

My problem is in the line `string id_string = Request.Params["id"];` the `id_string` takes as value `1,2` but the values of the integer `id_affectation` are `1` and `2`.

Why this happens? How can i fix it?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using strongly typed models for the POST action?

Comment: sorry , what do u mean by `strongly typed models` ?

Comment: Also your `else` block could be executing a `Model` that is `null` or a `Model[1]` that is `null`

Comment: Your code is difficult to read. Try formatting it please.

Comment: if id_string has value 1,2, int.Parse(id_string) will be supposed to throw an exception. dunno what your problem is.

Comment: My problem is that the value must be an integer as you see in the view `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="@a" />` the `a` is an integer

Comment: @Lamloumi Yes, but you're outputting it in a loop so more than 1 `id` is being submitted with the request!

Comment: How can i fix it? @GrantThomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this solution,
i have to change the order of the `form` and the `loop` to get a unique `id`

```
@foreach( Planning.Models.Affectation v in Model[1]){
<form action="\Travail\Validation_Reservation" method="post">

    if (v.Periode == 1) { s = "matinale"; }
    else { s = " Après midi"; }
    int a = v.Id_affectation; 
     <div><h5 style="color:blue">@i / Demande de reservation de vehicule @veh.Matricule : le @v.Date_affectation , la periode @s</h5>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@a" />
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="valider" />
   <input type="submit" name="btn" value="refuser" /></div>
    <br />
    i++;

        </form>
}
```